# Function for counting rows with changing criteria

Tags: python, function, loops, count, criteria

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
     season   stormid start_date   end_date  days
0      1970  SH071970 1970-01-04 1970-01-16    12
1      1970  SH081970 1970-01-07 1970-01-10     3
2      1970  SH111970 1970-01-11 1970-01-18     7
3      1970  SH121970 1970-01-22 1970-01-27     5
4      1970  SH131970 1970-02-01 1970-02-12    11
..      ...       ...        ...        ...   ...
569    2020  SH262020 2020-04-13 2020-04-17     4
570    2021  SH012021 2020-11-12 2020-11-18     6
571    2021  SH022021 2020-11-29 2020-12-11    12
572    2021  SH072021 2020-12-22 2020-12-31     9
573    2021  SH082021 2020-12-30 2020-12-31     1
```

and I would like to write a function (or use another solution) to count the number of rows in each season (in this case representing a year).

I have tried the following (without attempting to loop this process):

```
storms_1970_filter = storms.apply(lambda x : True if x['season'] == "1970" else False, axis=1) 

storms_1970 = len(storms_1970_filter[storms_1970_filter == True].index)
print('Number of storms in 1970 :', storms_1970)
```

But it returned a value of 0 when the value should be 10.

Ideally I would like an output something like:

```
Number of storms in 1970 : 10
Number of storms in 1971 : 14
Number of storms in 1972 : 11
Number of storms in 1973 : 16...
```

...and so on until 2020.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
d = df.groupby(['season'], as_index=False)['days'].count()
d.apply(lambda x: 'Number of storms in {} : {}'.format(x.season, x.days) if x.season<=2020 else None  ,axis=1)
```

Output:

```
0    Number of storms in 1970 : 3
1    Number of storms in 2020 : 2
2                            None
```

Or you can also you your seasonid column to count because it contains year at the end like `SH071970`.

```
yr =  [int(i[-4:]) for i in df.stormid.to_list()] ##[1970,1970..2021]
['Number of storms in {} : {}'.format(i , yr.count(i)) if i<=2020 else '' for i in set(yr)]
```